# How can I get a username from django User Model

Tags: python, django

I have the following where a comment is posted via a POST request

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("recipes/comments/", RecipeCommentView.as_view(), name="post_comment"),  # POST
]
```

Views.py

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
class RecipeCommentView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.RecipeComment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeCommentSerializer
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ["username"]

class RecipeCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    published_by = UserSerialiser(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.PublishedRecipeComment
        fields = ["recipe", "published_by", "content", "created_at"]
        ordering = ["position"]
```

Models.py

```
class RecipeComment(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="comments")
    published_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=2500)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I am using the User model from  django.contrib.auth.models, how can I have the username of the currently logged in user attached to the published_by field?

When I go to check the recently added comment that i have POSTed, the username does not show, it shows me null:

```
{
    "recipe": 1,
    "published_by": null,
    "content": "this is a comment",
    "created_at": "2021-07-24T12:13:10.391236Z"
}
```

I'm looking to populate the published_by field with the username of the user that has posted it.

Comment: Your purpose is not clear yet. cozk you already serialized username for published by.

You mean you want to render only currently authenticated user comment?

Comment: HI @anamul sorry that wasnt clear. Thats right i added the serialized username for published by, however when i go to check the models, all usernames are appearing as null. and I'm unsure how to get it to display the username. I've updated the question

Comment: It's null coz, in your comment table, the published_by fields is null, it's not populated

Comment: How can i get it to auto populate based on the logged in user's username that posts the comment?

Comment: Check my answer. Please accept it if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be work well, i tested it:

```
class RecipeCommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    published_by = UserSerialiser(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.PublishedRecipeComment
        fields = ["recipe", "published_by", "content", "created_at"]
        ordering = ["position"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        request = self.context['request']
        ModelClass = self.Meta.model
        
        instance = ModelClass.objects.create(
            **validated_data,
            **{
                'published_by': request.user
            }
        )
        return instance
```

Comment: I get the following:

AttributeError: 'RecipeCommentSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'
[24/Jul/2021 13:40:31] "POST /api/published-recipes/comments/ HTTP/1.1" 500 109664

Comment: Brother, i updated answer again later, please try with updated one

Comment: It will work, please copy the code again and try again.

If it works, accept the answer